# npm run build doesn't work and has error in webpack project

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, error-handling

today I enter npm run build in the terminal and then the project doesn't run anymore and it gave me 90 errors and 13 warnings.
It worked yesterday but today it doesn't. I really don't know what is the problem. I didn't change anything but a line of code that was javascript and has nothing to do with node modules or package JSON or ...

webpack version 5.69.1
node version 14.19.1
npm version 6.14.16

```
webpack 5.69.1 compiled with 90 errors and 13 warnings in 26714 ms
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! @mrghazian/editor@1.3.954 build: `webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --mode=production`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the @mrghazian/editor@1.3.954 build script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/ila/.npm/_logs/2022-04-12T07_22_51_190Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Take a look at "/home/ila/.npm/_logs/2022-04-12T07_22_51_190Z-debug.log", it's some times useful .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

I had added this line to one of my js files and it was the cause of all errors.

```
import { AsyncDependenciesBlock } from "webpack";
```

I deleted it now and all is good.